# UIImageView UIKit setImageWithURL memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimageview

Trying to debug my app, but my memory keeps increasing .

I have an app that pulls JSON from a web service with AFNetworking. I use UIKit + AFNetworking to load the URL string that I got from the JSON in UIImageView which are in a custom XIB table cell. I use `setImageForURL`.

When I load new JSON and hence new image URL's, my memory usage jumps by 2-7 mb each time. The old images are replaced in the UI by new ones. Live memory usage goes up and up. I've looked into the arrays holding the JSON and so forth - no leaks.

I suspect there is some image caching going on but I've never seen any information regarding image caching when using UIImageView with `setImageWithURL`. I've seen memory issues using `imageNamed` though.

Does `setImageWithURL` have the same memory issues as `imageNamed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setImageWithURL:` from AFNetworking handles the caching of the images downloaded with this method. The next time you call this for the same URL it will check the cache first to see if the image is cached (so no need to go network again).

From AFNetworking API:

> Asynchronously downloads an image from the specified URL, and sets it
>   once the request is finished.  Any previous image request for the
>   receiver will be cancelled.   If the image is cached locally, the
>   image is set immediately,  otherwise the specified placeholder image
>   will be set immediately,  and then the remote image will be set once
>   the request is finished.  By default, URL requests have a `Accept`
>   header field value of "image / *",  a cache policy of
>   `NSURLCacheStorageAllowed` and a timeout interval of 30 seconds,  and
>   are set not handle cookies. To configure URL requests differently, use
>   `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`

So there is indeed caching, hence memory usage.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So this makes my app a memory hog? In your experience does Apple reject these types of apps?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs The problem here is not about what Apple would do; why are you using AFNetworking to download the image? Do you need to cache it? The app is using so much memory so images must be big, so I guess they are not in a tableView. Give us some context and we might end up with a solution.

Comment: User gets location-based images and can refresh the table view with new images if they move to a new location. The old media is not persisted in any way. EG - I load location media in SF, then go to NYC and refresh; SF media is replaced in tableView with NYC media. SF media is not persisted in any way. AFNetworking is how I make the API call, which returns JSON. I use AF's UIImageView method setImageWithURL to load the media URL into a UIImageView.